# How do I delete a component after some time on MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, mongodb-atlas

I am currently creating a simple web app using Node.js and MongoDB. I am trying to delete whatever I enter into this field:
[shows what my webpage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUdqV.png)

When I enter something and click the button, it creates a collection in my MongoDB database. However, I want these collections to delete after some time. I have tried using `db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )`, but that did not work. I have also tried doing:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
    {
        **db.collection('test').find().toArray().createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 } )**
        .then(test => {
           res.render('index.ejs', {test: test})
            //console.log(results)
        })


        .catch(error => console.error(error))
       // res.render('index.ejs', {}); 
        //res.render(view, locals)
    })
```

but that did not work either. I am not sure what I have to do differently. Sorry if this was somewhat confusing, I am new to Node and MongoDB! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this works. (I use Mongoose and MongoDB) I hope may it help.

```
createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    expires: '15m',  // mention the time to expire
    default: Date.now 
}
```

Comment: did you add this after db.collection?